# Prevent Jenkins access on port 8080

Tags: jenkins, reverse-proxy

I have a bare-bones install of jenkins on my Ubuntu server that I installed using just `sudo apt-get install jenkins`, as a result, jenkins is now accessible from all the domains that point to my box by simply adding `:8080` on the the URL.

I have successfully configured apache to proxy jenkins to I can access it from `ci.mydomain.com`, but I cannot work out how to prevent jenkins from being accessible on port 8080.

Here is my apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ServerName ci.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyRequests     Off

    <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've followed the Ubuntu instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/a/236405/70084), but they didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: You can use `iptables` since it's Ubuntu, to block all non-local access to port 8080. `iptables -A INPUT -t tcp --dport 8080 -s localhost -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -A INPUT -t tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP`

Comment: @ionFish Thanks, it complains about the `--dport` option being unrecognised though, add this as an answer maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use iptables since it's Ubuntu, to block all non-local access to port 8080.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -s localhost -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

Comment: The response I get is `iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--dport"`

Comment: I'll look into that in a bit, I've got important stuff to do at this second.

Comment: it was `-p` instead of `-t` that was causing the dport issue, I have updated your answer

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution (without the need for IPtables):

- Prevent jenkins from being accessed outside of the server in port 8080:

  - Edit file /etc/default/jenkins
  - Add
    `HTTP_HOST=127.0.0.1`
  - In the end change the line:

    - From:
      `JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"`
    - To:
      `JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST"`
  - Restart the jenkins
    `systemctl restart jenkins`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to not work.

---

There is another solution, however, without the need for IPtables:

***Prevent jenkins from being accessed outside of the server in port 8080:***

- Edit file `/etc/default/jenkins`
- Add `HTTP_HOST=127.0.0.1`
- In the end change the line:

  From:

  ```
  JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"
  ```

  To:

  ```
  JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST"
  ```
- Restart the jenkins systemctl restart jenkins

Comment: I got the reason why /etc/default/jenkins does not work anymore, since from version 2.332.1, which relies on systemd rather than the init system. but when I upgrade to 2.332.3, it seem works again.